# Why the results of 2 approaches to calculate R2 score are different

Tags: numpy, statistics

In the linear model, *SST(total sum of squares) = SSR (residual sum of squares) + SSE (explained sum of squares)*, right?
So I calculated the R2 score with 2 different methods.

The shape of data is (n_sample, n_feature), and I want to calculate the R2 score by each feature.

1st: R2 = SSE/SST

```
def r2score(y_pred, y_true):
    SSE = np.sum((y_pred - y_true.mean(axis=0)) ** 2, axis=0)
    SST = np.sum((y_true - y_true.mean(axis=0)) ** 2, axis=0)
    return SSE / SST

array([0.3903272 , 0.61556043, 0.79316815, 0.27477445, 0.76132449,
       0.37335292, 0.67222515, 0.56178136, 0.37840461, 0.48753905,
       0.48425204, 0.40274203, 0.32436666, 0.73934064, 0.67582176,
       0.65503309, 0.74719551, 0.42158567, 0.35102711, 0.52308956,
       0.22078698, 0.30651726, 0.28614789, 0.43199096])
```

2st: R2 = 1 - SSR/SST

```
def r2score_same(y_pred, y_true):
    SSR = np.sum((y_true - y_pred) ** 2, axis=0)
    SST = np.sum((y_true - y_true.mean(axis=0)) ** 2, axis=0)
    return 1 - (SSR / SST)

array([0.43137207, 0.58980204, 0.75270556, 0.31230454, 0.80313592,
       0.2881272 , 0.68314465, 0.61986317, 0.36847796, 0.456864  ,
       0.35585449, 0.4385286 , 0.35472905, 0.66386517, 0.59598209,
       0.65243417, 0.70413723, 0.42801639, 0.43712039, 0.56682037,
       0.23902448, 0.34432634, 0.33884071, 0.42886742])
```

I can't understand why the results are not the same.

Please help me!

Comment: Can you explain the abbreviations?

Comment: @sai I misused abbreviations so I edited. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SSR/SST` and `1 - SSE/SST`? E.g.: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/linear-models-1-linear-regression-bb9614ec0eef

Comment: @Shaido It is very confusing to me because some articles explained that SSE(or ESS) is sum of squares of difference between prediction and mean. E.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_sum_of_squares. But in your example, they explained the same thing as SSR.

Comment: @장동엽: SSE and ESS are different which could be where the confusion lies. The link I used above or this wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_sums_of_squares should help clear things up. Note that both the explained sum of squares and residual sum of squares can be referred to as SSR. Try to follow one of the articles and use the same definition consistently.